# get data(php) from post(python)

Tags: php, python, server

I am currently develop website that will get data from python post.from 
rpi to website. I cant get the data from the server. this is my code:

python(post)

```
import requests
x = requests.post('http://sajatry.com/index.php?temperature=56')
print(x.text)
```

php(get)

```
<form action="" method="get">
<input type="text" name="temperature" 
value=
"<?php
 if($_GET['temperature']){
       $temperature=$_GET['temperature'];
       echo  $_GET['temperature'];  }
else
{ }
?>">
```

what is the problem in my code? no value in my page after refresh.
do i need write full url on tab?like this?

Comment: Sorry, it's very hard to understand... please, edit your post and get things straight, so somebody not involved in your code can actually understand what you want. I couldn't even tell where your python script starts or ends...

Comment: if I understand code then Python sends `56` to PHP which generates page with form - so Python in `x.content` should get form with value `56`. But to see this value in web browser you would have to save it in file/database when you get it from Python and later get it from file/database when you generate form for web browser.

Comment: so the process need to go through the database first? cant directly to the website or get from server? without having any storage that i created.

Comment: when python or any other language or tool send temperature then server uses it to generate form with value only for this tool, but it doesn't keep this value to generate form when other tool or browser will ask for form. Python can't fill form for you.

Comment: server would have to remeber this value in file/database to use it when it generate form for other tools or browsers.

Comment: so the best solution are by putting first data to the database.thank you for your idea and help. Do you have another idea besides this solution?